# Can't make partition with Gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I got Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on my laptop and unfortunately i need to use Windows. I tried using a virtual machine but didn't work out for me. I want to make a partition on the 1TB diks and get windows on it but Gparted wont let me resize or add new partitions. What can i do?

Comment: refer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/DeletePartition)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Is system using  UEFI or BIOS to boot? If BIOS with MBR have you used all 4 partitions? Post this above to preserve formatting: `sudo parted -l` Drives with MBR partitioning can only boot in BIOS mode with Windows. Drives partitioned with gpt only boot Windows in UEFI mode. And how you boot installer is then how it installs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to re-size a mounted hard disk then that's the problem; you can't make changes while the drive is mounted.

I mean that maybe you are trying to re-size your system's hard disk drive, try to re-size it with a Live CD so the HDD is not mounted.

Answer (score 0):

To use gparted correctly, you will want to use gksu to give root access. To do this, do:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
sudo gksu gparted
```

Then make your edits, apply them, and exit. If this helped make sure to check it and vote it up so others with this problem can see this!

Comment: you need to unmount the drive, you can't make changes while the drive is mounted

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to re-size a mounted hard disk then that's the problem; you can't make changes while the drive is mounted.

I mean that maybe you are trying to re-size your system's hard disk drive, try to re-size it with a Live CD so the HDD is not mounted.